# Building nested dataframe or dictionary from csv file for pyupset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visualization

I have a csv file in the following format,

```
Type_A, Type_B, Type_C
x1,x2,x3
y1,y2,y3
```

I need to build a nested dictionary or dataframe in the following format

```
Type_A
    ID  Value
    1   x1
    2   y1
Type_B
    ID  Value
    1   x2
    2   y2
Type_C
    ID  Value
    1   x3
    2   y3
```

In my first attempt, this is what I did

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df
Output:

     Type_A Type_B Type_C
0      x1      x2      x3
1      y1      y2      y3
```

I though all I need to do is read each column in a list and then add index before combining it in a dictionary or nested dataframe

so this is what I did to store them in a list.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(csv_file)
d1=df.Type_A.tolist()
d2=df.Type_B.tolist()
d3=df.Type_C.tolist()
```

then to add index used enumerate ()

```
d1_df=list(enumerate(d1, 1))
d2_df=list(enumerate(d2, 1))
d3_df=list(enumerate(d3, 1))

d1_df  # this gives me [(1, 'x1'), (2, 'y1')]
```

Now next I added lables Id and Value to dataframe

```
labels = ['Id','Value']
d1_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d1_df, columns=labels)
d2_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d2_df, columns=labels)
d3_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d3_df, columns=labels)


d1_df  # this gives me Id Value
       #            0   1    x1
       #            1   2    y1
```

Now I need to somehow nest them together in a dictionary

Comment: Can you make your key-value pairs unique so we can see a pattern? Maybe `x1,x2,x3` and `y1,y2,y3`?

Comment: actually all x is the same value, and all y is also same value, however there can  be cases where one of the x could be NaN. Think of it as 3 sets, set A, Set B and Set C all could have the same member but occasionally one of the set may be missing a member, in that case its loaded as NaN. I am trying to build this dict to use it in [PyUpset](https://github.com/ImSoErgodic/py-upset) which helps to visualizes overlaps between sets.

Comment: I think I have somewhat solved the problem and edited the question to reflect my progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of your

```
d1_dict=list(enumerate(d1, 1))
d2_dict=list(enumerate(d2, 1))
d3_dict=list(enumerate(d3, 1))
```

use

```
lst    = 3 * [None]            # Creating a list with 3 temporary items
lst[0] = list(enumerate(d1, 1))
lst[1] = list(enumerate(d2, 1))
lst[2] = list(enumerate(d3, 1))
```

(i.e. the *list* of lists; I chose the more appropriate name `lst` instead of your `dx_dict`).

Then create your nested dictionary:

```
result = {}
for col, id, lt in zip(df.columns, range(0, 3), lst):
    result[col] = {'ID': id}  # Creating column_name key and assigning inner dict to it
    result[col].update(lt)    # Adding key:value pairs from the list of pairs to inner dict
```

The value of the `result` will be

> {'Type_A': {'ID': 0, 1: 'x1', 2: 'y1'},
>    'Type_B': {'ID': 1, 1: ' x2', 2: ' y2'},
>    'Type_C': {'ID': 2, 1: ' x3', 2: ' y3'}}

(I didn't know which value you want for the ID key, so I used `range(0, 3)` for producing the sequential numbers, and I used numbered `x`, `y` in my `CSV` file to differentiate between columns.)

---

**Addendum 1:**

If I understood your edited question correctly, you wanted something else, so the last part of my code may be

```
result = {}
for col, lt in zip(df.columns, lst):
    result[col] = {'ID': 'Value'}
    result[col].update(lt)
result
```

giving the `result`:

> {'Type_A': {'ID': 'Value', 1: 'x1', 2: 'y1'},
>    'Type_B': {'ID': 'Value', 1: ' x2', 2: ' y2'},
>    'Type_C': {'ID': 'Value', 1: ' x3', 2: ' y3'}}

---

**Addendum 2:**

Or you wanted something else - so instead of commands in *Addendum 1* use just
this one command (directory comprehension)

```
result = {col: [('ID', 'Value')] + lt for col, lt in zip(df.columns, lst)}
```

giving the `result`:

> {'Type_A': [('ID', 'Value'), (1, 'x1'), (2, 'y1')],
>    'Type_B': [('ID', 'Value'), (1, ' x2'), (2, ' y2')],
>    'Type_C': [('ID', 'Value'), (1, ' x3'), (2, ' y3')]}

Comment: I have edited the original question for more clarity, I am very new to python so please pardon my wrong nomenclature.

Comment: Editing your original question in that way that the *current answers stay invalid* is not a very good thing. I suggest you to copy / paste your current question as a **new** question and then revert changes in *this* one.

Comment: I wrote *Addendum 1* and *Addendum 2* in my answer for your changed request.